# Bootstrap Tokenfield does not work in mobile Safari/iOS 8

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

I am using  [bootstrap tokenfield](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield) to instrument my email textbox to support multiple email input.

User types letter `a` in the email textbox (the one with red font in the picture) . A list of matched emails show up in a selection menu (the box  that shows the email `abc@gmail.com` in black)

After the user clicks and selected an email, the selected value is not captured. At the end I only got a letter `a` in the email textbox

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I am also using [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) in my project. It swallowed the `click` event of the selection menu (of css class `tt-selectable`) used by `bootstrap-tokenfield`

At the end it is my solution. Fork the twitter typeahead.js project and change the following line from

```
$el = $(that.templates.suggestion(context)).data(keys.obj, suggestion).data(keys.val, 
that.displayFn(suggestion)).addClass(that.classes.suggestion + " " 
+ that.classes.selectable);
```

to

```
$el = $(that.templates.suggestion(context)).data(keys.obj, suggestion).data(keys.val, 
that.displayFn(suggestion)).addClass(that.classes.suggestion + " " 
+ that.classes.selectable + " needsclick");
```

The additional css class `needsclick` will disable `fastclick` on this elements